# .htaccess php one constant value with multiple checkbox

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a list of items that are assigned to a specific category, and I want to filter them based on the districts.

My current URL looks like this:

```
category,5,some-category-name.html
```

and the .htaccess rule for it is:

```
RewriteRule ^category,([^-]*),([a-zA-Z0-9-]*).html$ category.php?id=$1
```

Now I want to limit the results by the districts selected by user, therefore I created a get form with empty action, containing checkboxes and a submit button:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="district[]" value="1"> District 1
    <input type="checkbox" name="district[]" value="2"> District 2
    <input type="checkbox" name="district[]" value="3"> District 3
    ...

    <input type="checkbox" name="district[]" value="50"> District 50
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

After submitting the form my link is in this format, which is fine enough to me.

```
category,5,some-category-name.html?district%5B%5D=20&district%5B%5D=21&district%5B%5D=4&district%5B%5D=25
```

However, I cannot access these values using PHP.
$_GET array contains only the category id, which is passed by .htaccess

Why is the rest not recognizable as GET data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `QSA` QueryStringAppend  flag to your Rule :

```
RewriteRule ^category,([^-]*),([a-zA-Z0- 9]*).html$ category.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

QSA is used to combine new and old Query stings.  Since your Rule's target already has a query string `id=` your new query strings are discarded by mod-rewrite when QSA isn't present.

From the Apache manual  :

When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the `[QSA]` flag causes the query strings to be combined.
Consider the following rule:
`RewriteRule "/pages/(.+)" "/page.php?page=$1" [ QSA ]`
With the `[QSA]` flag, a request for `/pages/123?one=two` will be mapped to `/page.php?page=123&one=two` . Without the `[QSA]` flag, that same request will be mapped to `/page.php?page=123` - that is, the existing query string will be discarded.